# How to modify the width of SVGs with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, articulate-storyline

I'm using Articulate Storyline and I want to modify the **width of a line** that I've created in the software using **Javascript**.

I already know that I can select any items (every item export to **SVGs** in Storyline's output) using This line of code:

```
 var item = $('[aria-label="Ourline"] svg')
```

Then we should be able to do some jQuery animations...

The problem is I can't modify the width attribute of the selected line using code below:

```
 $(item).attr("width","500");
```

**It just changes the position of the line 500 px to the right! What?!**

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Please note: The question has nothing to do with Storyline, It's all about SVGs and jquery.

Comment: If it's a `<line>` then you want to use `stroke-width` to set its width. Also, jQuery doesn't play nicely with SVG (last I checked - it might have changed since then).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I don't think it's so bad anymore but there are still some gotchas

Comment: I think I just modify the SVG container, not the image!!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/whLf02n8/

html:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>

<button id="7">7</button>
<button id="3">3</button>
```

javascript:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    const id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('svg circle').attr('stroke-width', id);
})
```